# Cheerio .css([property]) always returns null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I've recently started to work with **NodeJS** together with **Cheerio**. 
I'm getting an external URL, and loading the html with Cheerio.

I've stumbled upon an issue, whenever I'm trying to get the css properties of an element, `$.css([property])` always returns `null`, no matter what selector or property I give it.

What I'm doing:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
app = express();

app.get('/something_something', function (req, res) {
   request('some_url', function (error, response, html) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(html)
//
       console.log($('body').css('width'));
   }
}
```

This will always log `null`, no matter what selector or css property it has. (Please bear in mind I've over-checked if the jQuery object $('body') exists, and this happens no matter what URL there is)

Also, if I set `$('body').css('width', '100px')` 
and then `console.log($('body').css('width'))`, it will display 100px. So I'm guessing it's not the css() method itself, but the way Cheerio gets / doesn't get the styles of elements

*Other Cheerio methods work, such as `text()`, `val()`, `remove()`.

I'm still a NodeJS/Cheerio newbie, so any help, explanation, suggestion or info would be golden,

Cheerio!

Comment: Does your 'body' have a width style on it? If you want to get the actual width of the `body` tag then use $('body').width() http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: From what I can see in the Cheerio documentation, it does not support the width() method. Also,  the css() ALWAYS returns null, no matter if the property is 'font-size', 'color', or any other css property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheerio is a DOM interface. It parses HTML and allows you do access to the nodes and their properties. It's not a virtual browser that's trying to simulate an actual browser's view of HTML. Since it doesn't do any rendering or simulation of rendering it cannot tell you things that can only be determined when rendering concerns are involved (like dimensions of a DOM element).

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. I guess there's no way but the JSDOM way. Thanks a lot for your answer!